# Get user keyboard input in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I want to ask user for confirmation before running an specific jupyter notebook cell. So far I'm trying to get the user's answer using `input()` but it's not working as the cell keeps running without doing nothing.

Update: I'm running the notebook on VSCode

This is the code i have

```
print('WARNING: this cell uses XXXX limited resources:')
answer = input('-> Are you sure you want to run it? [yes| No]: ' )
if answer == 'yes' :
   #run some computation
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, this code works just fine (tested in Notebook and in Lab):

```
print('WARNING: this cell uses XXXX limited resources:')
answer = input('-> Are you sure you want to run it? [yes| no]: ' )
if answer == 'yes':
    print("YES")
else:
    print("NO")
print("some other job")
```

If the answer is "yes" the code in if is executed. Otherwise it executes what's in else (in case you need it). The last line is executed no matter what the answer is.

Answer (score 0):

Leaving a comment inside if loop will create `IndentationError: expected an indented block`. Please try as follow,

updated code :

```
print('WARNING: this cell uses XXXX limited resources:')
answer = input('-> Are you sure you want to run it? [yes| No]: ' )
if answer == 'yes' :
   print("answer is YES")
```

output :

```
WARNING: this cell uses XXXX limited resources:
-> Are you sure you want to run it? [yes| No]: yes
answer is YES
```

Yet not solved, then update your ipykernel using,

```
pip install --upgrade ipykernel
```

Comment: I updated my kernel but I keep having the same problem when I run the notebook on VSCode

Comment: In VSCode, go to `setting -> search "Code-runner: Run In Terminal"` and enable it. Now try.

Answer (score 0):

It seems user input issue. You can add lower() while accepting user input in your code like below & retry

print('WARNING: this cell uses XXXX limited resources:')

answer = input('-> Are you sure you want to run it? [yes| no]:')

if answer.lower() == 'yes': print("YES")

```
print("YES")
```